# Words or phrases for "showing an expression"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

The sentence is:

> He suddenly showed an extremely shocked expression."

Are there any good replacement for the verb/the phrase, like using "look", or "face" instead of "expression".

Comment: Suddenly he looked extremely shocked.

Comment: He suddenly appeared/looked shocked.  Suddenly, shock appeared on his face.  Shock showed on his face.  Shock took over his countenance.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use "mien" instead of expression.

Comment: @Nigel J "He suddenly showed an extremely shocked mien." is a good answer?

Comment: "a low-browed, frowning mien"https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mien&oq=mien&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.1073j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: why not?  Edwin Ashworth